# How can I disable internal Airflow errors to be logged via sentry but still se DAG execution errors?

Tags: airflow, sentry, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

I have enabled sentry [1.5.0] with apache airflow [Version 2.2.2] using following configuration in config file.

```
[sentry]
sentry_on: True
sentry_dsn: [DSN]
sentry_environment: dev
```

It seems to work just fine for all sort of errors. However Airflow internal errors like `Error while health checking kube watcher process. Process died for unknown reasons`, `broken_pipe`,`ApiException: too old resource version` etc are very frequent (close to 3k errors a day), which eats up my sentry quota very quickly.

While I am not sure how to fix those, I just want to disable those internal errors to be propagated via sentry and only trigger events for DAG execution errors/failures.

Note:The airflow executor I have set is `KubernetesExecutor` and my airflow is deployed in GKE.

Any help would be appreciated.